# Objective-C, Expression result unused, from some old code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I've getting the following warning `Expression result unused`

I've inherited the code from my predecessor and I've no idea how to fix this?

Obviously syntax has changed, any ideas ?

```
static float lowValue; 
static float highValue;

- (void) calculateHighLow{
    highValue;  //here
    lowValue;  // and here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously those two lines don't do anything so you can just remove them.

Answer (score 3):

Simply delete those two lines, they have no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If they aren't being used anywhere you can just delete the lines, or you can simply just decide to deal with the warning (though not a good idea).  You can also comment out the code, in case you figure out that might need them someday.